# Get Character Of IndexOf

Tags: vb.net

For an assigment my teacher is asking that we read from a file to find the characters of our name and place them at a label at the top of the form.

here is my code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    searchFile = File.OpenText("AcademicEthicsandIntegrityStatement.txt")


    Dim s As String = searchFile.ReadToEnd
    Dim b As String = s.IndexOf("b"c)
    Dim r As Integer = s.IndexOf("r"c)
    Dim i As Integer = s.IndexOf("i"c)
    Dim a As Integer = s.IndexOf("a"c)
    Dim n As Integer = s.IndexOf("n"c)
    Dim ec As Integer = s.IndexOf("e"c)

    Dim bRead = GetChar(s, b)
    Dim rRead = GetChar(s, r)
    Dim iRead = GetChar(s, i)
    Dim aRead = GetChar(s, a)
    Dim nRead = GetChar(s, n)
    Dim ecRead = GetChar(s, ec)
    lblName.Text = bRead + rRead + iRead + aRead + nRead + nRead + ecRead
End Sub
```

The text that is reading into my lbl is "gmcaad" instead of "brianne"

Im sure that I am missing something here or there is a much easier way to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Turn on Option Strict. `s.IndexOf("b"c)` returns an int32 but you are assigning it to a string variuable.

Comment: What if one the letters of your name is **NOT** present in the file?  In that case, `String.IndexOf()` will return a -1 value.  You're currently not checking for that scenario.

Comment: There's a bit of irony in getting SO to do your homework for you and a question that refers to a file called `AcademicEthicsandIntegrityStatement.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IndexOf` returns a zero-based index.
`GetChar` accepts a one-based index.

For consistency,

- if you want to use `IndexOf`, then use direct indexing instead of `GetChar`:

  ```
  Dim bRead = s(b)
  Dim rRead = s(r)
  ```
- if you want to use `GetChar`, then use `InStr` instead of `IndexOf` that also returns one-based values.

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you so much I used your first example. Just what I was looking for.

Comment: @BrianneRiggle Also please do [what Plutonix says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526361/get-character-of-indexof#comment70258727_41526361).

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer...case sensitive:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    With File.ReadAllText("AcademicEthicsandIntegrityStatement.txt")
        For Each C As Char In "Brianne".ToCharArray
            ' Note this is case-sensitive because it uses a binary comparison
            Dim Index As Integer = .IndexOf(C)
            If Index >= 0 Then lblName.Text &= .Substring(Index, 1)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

... and non-case sensitive:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    With File.ReadAllText("AcademicEthicsandIntegrityStatement.txt")
        For Each C As Char In "Brianne".ToCharArray
            ' Note this is not case-sensitive
            Dim Index As Integer = .IndexOf(C.ToString, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            If Index >= 0 Then lblName.Text &= .Substring(Index, 1)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```